# Trying to understand how the same secret key end up being calculated between Alice and Bob

Tags: diffie-hellman, keys, key-exchange

This is basically a duplicate of [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/x3dh-protocol-how-can-the-receiver-calculate-the-shared-key?rq=1) which was not answered very clearly. From the documentation, these are the calculations that happen for Alice to compute the shared secret key:

```
DH1 = DH(IKA, SPKB)
DH2 = DH(EKA, IKB)
DH3 = DH(EKA, SPKB)
DH4 = DH(EKA, OPKB)
SK = KDF(DH1 || DH2 || DH3 || DH4)
```

If I understand correctly,

IKA -> Alice's **private** identity key

SPKb -> Bob's **public** signed prekey

IKB -> Bob's **public** identity key

EKA -> Alice's **public** ephermal key

OPKB -> Bob's **public** one time prekey

From the documentation: 
"Bob retrieves Alice's identity key and ephemeral key from the message. Bob also loads his identity private key, and the private key(s) corresponding to whichever signed prekey and one-time prekey (if any) Alice used. Using these keys, Bob repeats the DH and KDF calculations from the previous section to derive SK, and then deletes the DH values."

I interpreted this as bob doing the same computations above with following values:

IKA -> Alice's **public** identity key

SPKB -> Bob's **private** signed prekey

IKB -> Bob's **private** identity key

EKA -> Alice's **public** ephermal key

OPKB -> Bob's **private** one time prekey

What I don't understand is how the same secret shared key end up being computed even though for DH1, DH2, DH3, DH4 different values are used for the keys. I am probably missing some property of the DH function along with how public keys are generated from private keys that makes this possible. Or my whole understanding of this is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

Comment: Is `EKA` the same as `EKa`? Is `OPKB` readable as `OPKb` for consistency? How are `SPKb` and `EPKn` computed in the protocol? The equations in the question show what Alice performs, but what does Bob perform? If that's similar with `a` and `b` exchanged, isn't the order for the concatenation in the input of `KDF` different?

Comment: To moderators: as stated in the question, it is very much a duplicate of [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52976/555). I suggest that we fix the present question here, until it is fully answerable; then either [if there is no answer] close the present question as duplicate, moving the [modified] question's text to the other answer; or [otherwise] close the other question as duplicate, copying [the accepted answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52980/555) here. Uh, isn't moderation things supposed to be simple?

Comment: @fgrieu I fixed the casing inconsistency, thank you for pointing it out. From the documentation here  https://signal.org/docs/specifications/x3dh/ "Bob repeats the DH and KDF calculations from the previous section to derive SK". My main question is how is Bob able to do that and calculate the same SK. Thank you.